# What does jsp response finally return?

Tags: jsp

I'm a little unsure about what is actually returned by a jsp. It's not mentioned in most of the learning material. Is the response html content?

jsp is a technology to mix html markups with java code. At server side, a jsp will be converted to a servlet. Servlet is to handle http request and return response. So when a jsp is requested, what is finally returned by this jsp servlet? Is the final reponse html page by translating the dynamic part into static html contents?

Or the response is still the mixture of html and java, and send back to browser. And browser will execute the java code?( I don't think browser can run java code )

Answer (score 2):

> jsp is a technology to mix html markups with java code

Though JSP enables us to write java code along with html, it is not advisable. The job of a JSP is to act as a View. It should not contain any java code. JSPs are meant for presentation purpose. You should look into [MVC architecture with servlets and jsp](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/) and what are the [advantages of JSP over servlets](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/12/30/advantages-jsp-servlets/)

> Or the response is still the mixture of html and java, and send back to browser. And browser will execute the java code?( I don't think browser can run java code )

A browser does not execute java code. It can only interpret html code. JSP will return whatever is executable on browser. i.e. javascript, css, images, jsons, html and many more things a browser can interpret.

It can be done using `response.setContentType("application/json");`

Answer (score 0):

response can be anything.we can set it through

examples:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.setContentType("image/gif");
```

It is a information to browser from server side.